# Interpreter fails to parse Numbers and Percents

Tags: interpreter

`Interpreter` fails on `Association` with mixed type Values:

```
<|"a" -> 1, "b" -> "99%"|> // Map[Interpreter["Number" | "Percent"]]
```

> MapThread::mptd: "Object
>   !(Interpreter`PackageScope`parserSemantic[...

(long list of warnings)

```
<|"a" -> Replace[
   Verbatim[Alternatives][
     Interpreter`DependentTypes`PackagePrivate`a_] :> 
    Interpreter`DependentTypes`PackagePrivate`a, {0, \[Infinity]}], 
 "b" -> Quantity[99, "Percent"]|>
```

man pages say `Alternative` forms are tried in sequence. Without that sequence, of course the percent will not be parsed, but the 1 is.

```
<|"a" -> 1, "b" -> "99%"|> // Map[Interpreter["Number"]]
```

> <|"a" -> 1, "b" ->Failure[...enter a valid number...]] |>

Comment: Is there a question here?  If you want a place to simply post issues you encounter, I suspect that Wolfram's Community site would be the more appropriate place.

Comment: @chuy, `Prepend["Why does "]`

Answer (score 5):

This has nothing to do with `Association`.

```
{1, "99%"} // Map[Interpreter["Number" | "Percent"]]
```

fails as well.

Originally, I thought the answer could be found (more or less) in the documentation where the first line of the Details and Option section says:

> Interpreter[...][input] applies the interpreter to a particular input,
>   which is typically a string.

That "*typically a string*" suggests that the input might be something different than a string, but I don't believe that there is one example among the multitude of examples that is is using anything other than a string. And indeed, if you change your `1` to a `"1"` your problem goes away:

```
<|"a" -> "1", "b" -> "99%"|> //Map[Interpreter["Number" | "Percent"]]
(* <|"a" -> 1, "b" -> Quantity[99, "Percent"]|> *)
```

So, documentation error? Well, no. This is not the end of the story, as both

```
Interpreter["Number"][1]
(* 1 *)
```

and

```
Interpreter["Percent"][1]
(* Quantity[1, "Percent"] *)
```

do work without error messages. So, non-string input is altogether possible.

It is the combination with `Alternatives` that doesn't work.

```
Interpreter["Number" | "Percent"][1]
```

gives the voluminous set of error messages again, with the string version working OK:

```
Interpreter["Number" | "Percent"]["1"]
(* 1 *)
```

For now, I'd call it a bug. A workaround would be to apply `ToString` where necessary.

Comment: As you say, `Alternatives` within `Interpreter` indeed seems to be the root cause. Note that `<|"a" -> 1, "b" -> "99%"|> // Map[Interpreter["SemanticExpression"]]` works just fine to return: `<|"a" -> 1, "b" -> Quantity[99, "Percent"]|>`. (+1)